# Flex TileList item rollover effect

Tags: apache-flex

I am using a flex tilelist to display some images. 
I want the image being rolled over in tilelist to zoom out a bit. 
I tried itemRollOver property of tilelist but didnt succeed.
The rollOverEffect property of tilelist zooms out entire tilelist which is not what I want.
I want only the rolled over item to zoom out.
How can I do it.
Please anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom item renderer for the tilelist. Listen for the rollover event in this, and do the resize event in it.